# Modal insert occurring before data is loaded

Tags: javascript

I have a set of records displayed where an individual record's info can be edited by clicking on the edit link next to the desired record. Upon clicking the link, I insert an edit modal via javascript and populate the fields with that record's data.

What I'm finding is around 60% of the time, the fields display null, implying that the modal is being inserted into the DOM faster than I can populate the fields, which I do so by pulling the records data attributes via getAttribute(). It must be milliseconds difference. Each edit button has a set of data attributes:

```
<span class="edit-btn" data-id="gREwTytnO" data-month="11" data-year="2020" data-name="John Doe">
    <span class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>Edit
</span>
```

Here is a line from the modal:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Month (mm)" class="month-field" id="month" value="' + event.target.getAttribute('data-month') + '" required>
```

I then insert it into the DOM. What it seems like is that `event.target.getAttribute()` has not finished pulling the data from the DOM and execution continues and inserts the modal anyway.

What options do I have to ensure that before the modal is inserted into the DOM, the attributes are all loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option, although there are probably much more efficient ways to do it, would be to collect all of your data- attributes into variables local to the function that displays the modal before actually displaying it.

That way you don't end up with a race condition where you're hoping `event.target.getAttribute()` can do its job before the value is needed.

Comment: This was the way to go. In my get function I ended up populating an array of data to be pulled from when the edit modal popped. Thanks.